# Get Mean amplitude(only) of .wav from sox

Tags: cmd, wav, sox

```
C:\Program Files\sox-14-4-0>sox Sample.wav -n stat
```

The above code gives below result

```
Samples read:             26640
Length (seconds):      3.330000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.515625
Minimum amplitude:    -0.734375
Midline amplitude:    -0.109375
Mean    norm:          0.058691
Mean    amplitude:     0.000122
RMS     amplitude:     0.101146
Maximum delta:         0.550781
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.021387
RMS     delta:         0.041831
Rough   frequency:          526
Volume adjustment:        1.362
```

Now i need only Mean amplitude. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways.

Method 1:

```
"C:\Program Files\sox-14-4-0\sox" Sample.wav -n stat | find "Mean    amplitude: " > %TMP%\amp.tmp
set /p meanAMP=<%TMP%\amp.tmp
set meanAMP=%meanAMP:*:     =%
del %TMP%\amp.tmp
echo %meanAMP%
```

---

Method 2:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%x in ('"%ProgramFiles%\sox-14-4-0\sox" Sample.wav -n stat') do (
  if "%%x %%y"=="Mean amplitude:" set meanAMP=%%z
)
echo %meanAMP%
```

---

### Fastest:

Method 3:

```
for /f "skip=7 tokens=1-3" %%x in ('"%ProgramFiles%\sox-14-4-0\sox" Sample.wav -n stat') do (
  if "%%x %%y"=="Mean amplitude:" set meanAMP=%%z
)
echo %meanAMP%
```

---

Method 4:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%x in ('"%ProgramFiles%\sox-14-4-0\sox" Sample.wav -n stat ^| find "Mean    amplitude:"') do (
  set meanAMP=%%z
)
echo %meanAMP%
```

I suspect that method 3 will be the fastest because:

Method 1 uses a lot of steps, including the external program `find`, the creation, access and deletion of a temporary file, and the redefinition of a variable.

Method 2 examines all the output of `SOX`.

Method 4 uses the external program `find` which slows down execution.

Method 3 actually skips the first 7 lines of output from `SOX` and THEN begins to evaluate the output.

**NOTE:** Methods 2-4 can all be done on a single line, just remove the `(` and `)`.

**EDIT:** Fixed some errors in the code.

**NOTE:** To use from the command prompt Method 1 should work as-is.  Methods 2-4 require changing all `%%`'s to `%`'s.

For example, you can paste this directly into `cmd`:

```
for /f "skip=7 tokens=1-3" %%x in ('"%ProgramFiles%\sox-14-4-0\sox" Sample.wav -n stat') do (
  if "%x %y"=="Mean amplitude:" set meanAMP=%z
)
echo %meanAMP%
```

Notice that this is almost an exact copy of method 3, except I changed `%%x`, `%%y` and `%%z` into `%x`, `%y` and `%z` respectively.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answers. But i don't know where to paste these codes. When i tried in cmd, i get **"'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."**

Or i get 

**%%x was unexpected at this time.**

Comment: @Gaan_setaglA - I've fixed the code to remove the `is not recognized` errors.  Method 1 should work as is in either a batch file, or at a cmd prompt.  Method2 2-4 should either be in a batch file, or change all `%%`'s to `%`'s.